# NodeJS send a token in the url when redirecting user after login

Tags: node.js

I'm building an application with nextJs for frontend, and nodejs for backend with using passportjs and facebook strategy for authentication.
And I want to send a token for the client after the authentication. After some research I've found the solution below:

```
router.get(
  "/auth/facebook/callback",
  passport.authenticate("facebook", {
    session: false,
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    // generate token ...
    res.redirect(`localhost:3000/home?%{token}`)
  }
)
```

And then, in the client, I would get the token in the query params and save it on localstorage to use it in the requests.

But my question is: does this solution leaves the token too vulnerable? is there a better way to do it?

If anyone could help me. I'm kinda lost in what's the best way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the access token through "response | res", eliminating some security problems when passing the entire URL.

```
res.status(200).send({ token: token });
```

And then access the response on the client.